# Secure Websockets WSS in Play Framework 2.2.x?

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.2

Is it at all possible to setup Websocket's WSS in Play?
If so, what are the necessary steps?

Comment: A similar question suggested to use nginx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590674/how-to-use-tls-in-playframework-websockets-wss ?