# SignalR: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: websocket, signalr

I have just started working with SignalR. I have implemented real-time data reflection on my site using signalr. I was getting "Error during Web-Socket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400" error on console with when trying to connect with web-socket.

Application is developed with Asp.net MVC - signalR 2.0.3 and hosted On Windows server 2012 - IIS 8

I found one solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344378/intermittent-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-400-on)

It says that We need website to point to HTTPS (and avail SSL) then http to work with web-socket. And my Issue resolved too. My doubt is - cant we solve this issue without using HTTPS ? As each website might not require to be hosted on HTTPS (which requires SSL).

Comment: Your website may be served through HTTP while your WebSocket connects over SSL(WSS). This is a normal/working scheme...

Comment: My request points to ws://* only and not wss://* which displyed in console error

Comment: Well, I do not know how SignalR functions but I know it is possible to server HTML over HTTP and websocket over SSL...

Answer (score 36):

use this tag in your web.config file :

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="40960" targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

under `<system.web>` tag.
Describe your target framework.Error will be disappear

Comment: @DanielMinnaar, Sure! Because Microsoft.

Answer (score 6):

I was having same issue in .Net Core Web API with Angular 8 front end. The issue in my case was the Websocket protocol was not installed on server. Installed it from Server manager -> Add Roles and Features and it worked

[image]

Comment: This also works for me.
Ionic + .Net Core + SignalR application

Comment: This also works for me. Vue + .Net Core + SignalR application

Answer (score 5):

If the problem are the proxies that exists in the path from client to server, there is nothing you can do but complain to your provider (both client and server).

[How HTML5 Web Sockets Interact With Proxy Servers](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers)

By using a secure connection, you ensure that no proxy is going to mess with your connection.

Answer (score 2):

This 400 error can also happen if you are running on multiple servers behind a load balancer. Inspect the body of the 400 response (ex., using Fiddler) and see if you find this: `The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format`.  If so, then your problem may be that you are not using the same machine key on each application server.

See this answer for details on the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43479474/979202

Answer (score 0):

If you're behind Nginx, add these three lines (the ones starting with `proxy_`):

```
server {       
    listen       443; # Or 80 or whatever
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    ...
}
```

HTTPS/HTTP is not the issue. WSS will be automatically used on HTTPS pages, and WS used on HTTP, without any manual setting.