# Enabling websockets on Heroku

Tags: heroku, websocket

I need help with enabling websockets through Heroku labs.

I execute **'heroku labs:enable websockets -a myapp'** through the Toolbelt an I get - **No such feature: websockets**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because Web Sockets are no longer a labs feature.

Web Sockets [are now generally available](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/7/7/websockets_now_ga).

> If you are creating a new application on Heroku, there is no need to
>   enable WebSockets or to configure your application to use the new
>   router — this is now the default configuration.

Comment: I have a created an app recently and it doesn't seem to have Web Sockets enabled. In my Meteor app I'm getting: `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400` Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a problem with Heroku as such. Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344378/intermittent-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-400-on