# Websocket handshake error with MeteorJS App on Modulus

Tags: meteor, dns, modulus

The case is, I have a MeteorJS app deployed on modulus.
When using the Modulus URL e.g. "myapp-12312.onmodulus.net" everything is working fine.

BUT when using a Custom Domain and access the app via "myapp.mydomain.com" (configured in my DNS) I get the following error message:

"Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400"

Anyone had the same problem with MeteorJS and domains?

kind regards

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem on my Android phone. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Is your app using HTTPS? Another answer suggests that this is a problem with in-secure HTTP connections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344378/intermittent-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-400-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and got a SSL certificate for my domain, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344378/intermittent-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-400-on).

Everything is working fine now.