# Play framework: Secure WebSocket (WSS)

Tags: nginx, https, playframework, websocket

I've read in this post ([How to use TLS in Play!Framework WebSockets ("wss://")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590674/how-to-use-tls-in-playframework-websockets-wss)) that Play framework 2.x doesn't support Secure WebSocket. Someone suggests to use nginx proxy. I'm thinking about configuring Play to serve HTTPS (as described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ConfiguringHttps).
Would this work with a WSS client endpoint and is this a correct approach?
Is there an alternative approach to nginx or https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does work i have tried it in play 2.1.4. Worked fine for me, but i have only tested it in google chrome and firefox.

Comment: My clients are routers. Initially Java clients to simulate them. Then I will use Linux and C. I hope it will work. Thanks.

Comment: I have onlly tried it on linux with java.  If you face any issue please comment it here. I will try my best to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the right approach is to run Play configured to run https **(-Dhttps.port=9443)** and then you can use **wss://**

Tested on Windows and Play 2.2.x

Comment: hi jfuentes, I tried using -Dhttps.port=9443, but I am getting the below warning message and the connection is getting closed immediately. Warning: Generated key with self signed certificate for HTTPS. This should NOT be used in production.